# How can i avoid congestion between x and y axis in my graph with highcharts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

[image: congestion between x and y]

the above graph shows the congestion between x and y coordinates how can that be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add an offset to the labels of either `xAxis` or `yAxis` with

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    x: 5,
    y: 5
  }
}
```

This will move the label 5 points relative to the axis.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the scale on the X axis by for example formatting x axis data to a Date without time information?

Comment: how to increase scale on x axis?

Comment: by making the label in xAxis to align:'left' congestion is avoided